# Method selectedFeatures() works too slow in QGIS 3 Python console

Tags: pyqgis, performance, qgis-python-console

I loaded spatial table(about 100 millions rows) from PostgreSQL(PostGIS) in QGIS3 and use method **selectedFeatures()** in **QGIS 3** **Python console**. For such big tables it work very slow (it takes up to 10 minutes).

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceUri

uri1 = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri1.setUseEstimatedMetadata(True)
uri1.setConnection(str(host), str(port), str(database), str(user), str(password))
uri1.setDataSource (schema , tablename, geometrycol)
layer=QgsVectorLayer (uri1 .uri(False), tablename, "postgres")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

iface = qgis.utils.iface
activeLayer = iface.activeLayer()
selected_features = activeLayer.selectedFeatures()
```

In QGIS 2 these methods work much more faster(several seconds).

How can I solve this problem? I want to get copy of selected data for several seconds.

Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?

**POSTGIS**="2.5.1 r17027"

**PostgreSQL** 11.1 (Ubuntu 11.1-1.pgdg18.04+1)

**QGIS version**:3.8.3-Zanzibar

**OS**: Windows Server 2019

**Python** version: Python 3.7.0*

Comment: Method works
correct in QGIS 2. I found some differences between  pyqgis2 API:
https://qgis.org/api/2.18/qgsvectorlayer_8cpp_source.html  (QGIS2 :line
2732)

and  pyqgis3 API:

https://qgis.org/api/2.18/qgsvectorlayer_8cpp_source.html  (QGIS2 :line
2732)

And one more interesting fact: Working time increase proportionally to the
number of user-selected features (Working_time ≈ n*5 min, where n - number
of user-selected features).

And I still did not find solution this problem. If someone have some idea
please share with me.